# Print 2 pages 10x30cm double on 2 duplex

Tags: printing

I have a flyer with the format 10x29.7 cm.

How do I have to format the pdf so I can print 2 times the frontpage on one side and 2 times the backside on the back?

I have a cutter that will cut the bunch legthwise at the end.

I can export as PDF no problem, but the main goal is to have the flyer **without borders** on the whole page twice, so I only have to cut once.

Comment: What format is the original flyer in? Word, PDF, …? And do you have one document for the front side and one for the back side?

Comment: I use scribus and can create a pdf-document as needed, but I am not sure which is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

*If* the original is a two page flyer in Microsoft Word with the correct page dimensions of the pages (10 x 29.7 cm), where page 1 is the front page and page 2 is the backside, you can print the PDF in this way:

1. Press Ctrl+P to open the print dialog.
2. Select [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/) or a similar PDF printer as the printer.
3. Select 2 pages per sheet.
4. Tell Word to print pages: 1,1,2,2.
5. Press OK to print.

You won't get any control of the position of the back side compared to the front side. If you need to adjust that, adjust it on page two of the document. After one test print to the physical printer (remember to print the PDF in 100% zoom) you should be able to measure exactly how much off the backside is and then adjust the original backside page accordingly and repeat the process.